# Github actions: Creating releases for multiple branches in a single workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I am new to github actions, I have a good idea on how they work but I am having troubles creating releases for multiple branches. Is it possible to create multiple releases from multiple branches in a single workflow?

I currently having working workflow that generates and deploys releases for my main branch. I now want to create releases for a second branch that is slightly similar but has varying functionality.

My problem and my question is:

- How does the github workflow differentiate between the main branch and the other branch to create the releases from the .yml file in the main branch? I know you can use `if: github.ref` but I am not sure how to go about doing it.
- Should I create a seperate .yml in the second branch, with a separate workflow and create different tag?
- Should I create another entry in my matrix that only relies on the second branch?

Below is my .yml in my main branch:

```
name: "CI/CD"

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, example ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, example ]

env:
  QT_VERSION: 5.15.2
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
  packageGlob: justAnExample-continuous-*.*

jobs:
  main_build:
    name: ${{ matrix.config.name }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
        - {
           name: "Linux-amd64"
           , os: ubuntu-18.04
           , QT_INST_DIR: /opt
           , install_ninja: "sudo apt-get install -qq ninja-build"
           , install_pkgs: "sudo apt-get -qq install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0"
           , bcInstallPrefix: /usr
           , build_justAnExample: "DESTDIR=./appdir ninja install; find ./appdir; mv default.png ./appdir/usr/share/"
           , rename_package: "mv justAnExample-*.tar.xz justAnExample-continuous-linux-x86_64.tar.xz"
          }
        - {
            name: "Windows-x64", WIN_ARCH: "x64"
            , os: windows-latest
            , QT_INST_DIR: "C:/", QTDIR: "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64", QT_ARCH: win64_msvc2019_64
            , install_ninja: "choco install ninja"
            , bcInstallPrefix: justAnExample-continuous
            , build_justAnExample: "ninja install"
            , rename_package: "mv justAnExample-*.zip justAnExample-continuous-win64.zip && mv justAnExample-*.exe justAnExample-continuous-win64-installer.exe"
          }
        - {
            name: "Windows-x86"
            , os: windows-latest, WIN_ARCH: "amd64_x86"
            , QT_INST_DIR: "C:/", QTDIR: "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019", QT_ARCH: win32_msvc2019
            , install_ninja: "choco install ninja"
            , bcInstallPrefix: justAnExample-continuous
            , build_justAnExample: "ninja install"
            , rename_package: "ls -R && mv justAnExample-*.zip justAnExample-continuous-win32.zip && mv justAnExample-*.exe justAnExample-continuous-win32-installer.exe"
          }
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Env Script (Windows)
      uses: ilammy/msvc-dev-cmd@v1
      if: runner.os == 'Windows'
      with:
        arch: ${{matrix.config.WIN_ARCH}}
  
    - name: Install Ninja
      run: ${{matrix.config.install_ninja}}
    
    - name: Install Packages
      if: runner.os == 'Linux'
      run: ${{matrix.config.install_pkgs}}

    - name: Install Qt
      uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v2.14.0
      with:
       dir: ${{matrix.config.QT_INST_DIR}}
       arch: ${{matrix.config.QT_ARCH}}
       version: ${{env.QT_VERSION}}

    - name: Build justAnExample
      id: main_build
      run: |
        cmake -S. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${{matrix.config.bcInstallPrefix}} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
        ${{matrix.config.build_justAnExample}}
    - name: CPack
      run: cpack
      
    - name: Build AppImage (Linux)
      if: runner.os == 'Linux'
      run: |
        wget -c "https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/releases/download/continuous/linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage"
        export VERSION=continuous
        chmod a+x linuxdeployqt*.AppImage
        unset QTDIR; unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH; unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        ./linuxdeployqt*.AppImage ./appdir/usr/share/applications/*.desktop -appimage -extra-plugins=iconengines,platformthemes/libqxdgdesktopportal.so
        
    - name: Prepare Upload
      shell: bash
      run: ${{matrix.config.rename_package}}

    - name: Upload
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/${{env.packageGlob}}

  release_assets:
    name: Release
    needs: main_Build
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Download Files
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2

    - name: Move Files
      run: |
        mv artifact/* ${{github.workspace}}
    - name: Deploy Package
      uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
      with:
       repo_token: "${{ secrets.DEPLOYTOKEN }}"
       automatic_release_tag: "continuous-main"
       prerelease: false
       title: "Continuous Build"
       files: ${{env.packageGlob}}
```

Comment: You can use action inheritance for different releases or to use a matrix https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Answer (score 2):

I have used tags, and I can tag a commit (in any branch) to be used for the action. Below is a part of my workflow file (yml):

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - Publish*
```

So, any commit tag starts with 'Publish' will be used for the action (e.g. Publish1).
You can see more details about using tags in: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Answer (score 2):

You can mention multiple branch as given in documentation.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - 'releases/**'
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions